# Find bracket which are not closed without using regex in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find out if any bracket is not closed without using regex, this is what I am trying but it is failed when the string are like "re(d))()(()"

```
def bracket(str):
   return [0,1][str.count(')') == str.count('(')]
s = "re(d))()(()"
print bracket(s)
```

Is there any better way to do it.

Comment: Iterate through the string.  Incremeting by one if you see a ( and decrement by one if you see a ).  Fail if you ever get -1, or if you are above 1 when you end.

Comment: Also note that "without using regex" is not a requirement at all, since it is quite impossible to do that via regex. Simply because regular expressions can't handle "nesting".

Comment: @freakish that perfectly make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def check_brackets(s):
    counter = 0
    for chr in s:
        if chr == "(":
            counter += 1
        elif chr == ")":
            counter -= 1
            if counter < 0:
                return False
    return counter == 0
```

**EDIT**: Here's how you can do that with many different bracket types:

```
BRACKETS = ("()", "[]", "{}")
def check_brackets(s):
    counter = []
    for chr in s:
        for br in BRACKETS:
            open = br[0]
            close = br[1]
            if chr == open:
                counter.append(open)
                break
            elif chr == close:
                try:
                    last_br = counter.pop()
                except IndexError:
                    return False
                if last_br != open: # ensures that the end matches the beginnig
                    return False
    return not bool(counter)
```

Note that it will mark `([)]` as invalid (which is as it should be).

Comment: Sorry I found it and I deleted my comment.

Comment: counter < 0 should be inside the elif.  Because you don't need to test if you havent decreased the counter.

Comment: @Taemyr Not really important, but I've fixed it.

Comment: if there are more than one bracket type like if i include '[]' ? how can i proceed that.

Comment: @yopy Count per bracket type. However there are some cases like `[(])`. If you want to ensure that this is incorrect, then you will probably need a proper parser. Much harder to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

Using the approach from [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm):

```
from collections import deque
def solve(s):
    queue = deque()
    for c in s:
        if c == ')':
            if queue:
               queue.pop()
               continue
            return False
        elif c == '(':
            queue.append(c)
    return not bool(queue)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> solve("re(d))()(()")
False
>>> solve("(re(d)()())")
True
>>> solve("(re(d)()((())))")
True
>>> solve(")))(((")
False
```

Comment: Overkill for this problem, although if OP intends to actually do something with the things he is parsing then this makes more sense.

Comment: nobody doubts the correctness? `print solve(')')` outputs true

Comment: @zhangxaochen Good catch, fixed the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [44]: from collections import deque
    ...: def solve(s):
    ...:    queue = deque()
    ...:    for c in s:
    ...:        if c == ')':
    ...:            if queue:
    ...:                queue.pop()
    ...:            else:
    ...:                return False
    ...:        elif c == '(':
    ...:            queue.append(c)
    ...:    return not bool(queue)
    ...: 

In [45]: print solve('()'), solve('())'), solve('re(d))()(()')
True False False
```

it's important to check if the deque being empty when a ')' comes

Comment: i think duplicate answer.

Comment: @yopy i add `else: return False` based on Ashwini Chaudhary's answer, other wise it will print True for case like ')()'